# Get URL of downloaded video in youtube_dl progress hook

Tags: python, youtube-dl

How can I get the URL of a video that I'm downloading using `youtube_dl`?

I can use progress hooks to get other characteristics of the download, like the file path:

```
def progress_hook(response):
    if response["status"] == "finished":
        file_name = response["filename"]

ydl_opts = {
    'progress_hooks': [progress_hook]
}
```

I also want to get the URL that the file came from. I can't figure out how to do that. Something like `url = response["url"]` would be good, but [there aren't very many options](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py#L234) with progress hooks.

Comment: If you are using just one YoutubeDL object why not make URL a module level variable?

Comment: Okay, would you explain how I can do that?

Comment: @VukVojta I probably understand what you're saying now. You're suggesting I just save the URL that I passed to my `YoutubeDL` object to download and reference it later. Unfortunately, there's not a super easy way to do that unless I restructure my program. I was hoping for a way to get the URL of whatever file was just downloaded. If I have to restructure it to download one at a time I guess I can do that, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there doesn't seem to be a way to do this, I restructured my program to only download one at a time, so it was very explicit to me which was being downloaded.

To use this, you create an instance of it, passing the list of URLs you want to download to the constructor.

Then, when you're ready, you can call `start_download_process` on the object. It will wait until the current track is finished and the `progress_hook` is fully done before downloading another.

```
class YoutubeManager:
    def __init__(self, url_list):
        self.base_url = "https://www.youtube.com"
        self.current_download_url = ""
        self.url_list = url_list

        self.currently_downloading = False
        self.current_download_count = 0

        ydl_opts = {
            'format': 'bestaudio/best',
            'noplaylist': True,
            'continue_dl': True,
            'progress_hooks': [self.progress_hook],
            'postprocessors': [{
                'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
                'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
                'preferredquality': '192', }]
        }

        self.youtube_dl_manager = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts)
        

    def start_download_process(self):
        self.currently_downloading = True
        self.current_download_count += 1

        with self.youtube_dl_manager as youtube_dl_manager:
            self.current_download_url = self.url_list.pop()
            youtube_dl_manager.download([self.base_url + self.current_download_url])

    def continue_download_process(self):
        self.current_download_count += 1
        with self.youtube_dl_manager as youtube_dl_manager:
            self.current_download_url = self.url_list.pop()
            youtube_dl_manager.download([self.base_url + self.current_download_url])

    def progress_hook(self, response):
        if response["status"] == "finished":
            file_name = response["filename"]
            print("Downloaded " + file_name)

            # You can do something with self.current_download_url and file_name here

            if len(self.url_list) != 0:
                self.continue_download_process()
            else:
                self.currently_downloading = False
```

Comment: Going from asking how to make a variable module level to writing a lean mean python class in 5 days is an achievement in itself and a good example of what I am on the way to need to do.